# delete kubernetes pods which status shows 'CrashLoopBackOff' via shell script

Tags: bash, automation, kubernetes-pod, resource-cleanup

I trying to write a script to delete pods status `CrashLoopBackOff` from all namespaces.

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script is basically check all avialble namespaces 
# and delete pods in any particular status like 'Evicted',
# 'CrashLoopBackOff','Terminating'

NAMESPACE="popeye"
delpods2=$(sudo kubectl get pods -n ${NAMESPACE} |
  grep -i 'CrashLoopBackOff' |
  awk '{print $1 }')    

for i in ${delpods2[@]}; do

  sudo kubectl delete pod $i --force=true --wait=false \
    --grace-period=0 -n ${NAMESPACE}
    
done
```

The above script works with a specified namespace but how we can set if I have multiple namespaces and check for the pods in each one.

Comment: Just make an outer loop that loops over namespace names?

Comment: something like `kubectl get pod -A |awk  '$4 ~ /^CrashLoopBackOff$/{print $1,$2}'|while IFS=" " read ns pod; do echo "k delete pod $pod -n $ns --force --grace-period 0" ;done`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a better way for doing this.
You can simply run

```
kubectl delete pods --field-selector status.phase=Failed --all-namespaces
```

This way is much simple and neat.
However, note that this doesn't delete `evicted` and `CrashLoopBackOff` pods only , but also pods that have failed due to different reasons ("ContainerCannotRun", "Error", "ContainerCreating", etc.).

We can also make this even better. Using `-A` instead of `--all-namespaces`.

So, the final command is

```
kubectl delete pods --field-selector status.phase=Failed -A
```

Happy Hacking!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```bash
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep 'CrashLoopBackOff' | awk '{print $2 " --namespace=" $1}' | xargs kubectl delete pod
```